# Moongose - got a schema but its being ignored somehow

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got a moongose schema -

```
mongoose.Schema(
   {
      companyName: {
         type: String,
         required: true
      }
   },
   {
      companyEmail: {
         type: String,
         required: true
      }
   },
   {
      companySite: {
         type: String,
         required: true
      }
   })
```

If I test it in e.g. Postman, if I submit empty object it properly throws an error:

`"Path 'companyName' is required.",`

However, if I enter just the `companyName`, the post request is being properly processed, even if I didnt enter `companyEmail` or `companySite` and they are required. Looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mongoose.Schema` function takes only one argument describing the data model. However, in JS the number of arguments isn't validated at time of function call, so your call with three arguments doesn't fail just that last two are simply ignored. Effectively the schema created by your code only contains `companyName` field.

You should create your schema like this to make it validate (and honor) all three fields.

```
mongoose.Schema({
    companyName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    companyEmail: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    companySite: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using html form data, the fields will still get processed as an empty string "". On the backend, I would check if companyName.length > 0, and handle the error before inserting the data to mongodb